# Paired + unpaired repeated measures in same test

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, missing-data, sas

hope you can help me with this. I have the same survey that has been repeated each half year for almost 3 years (6 repeated surveys) with approximately 500 responses each time. Some of the respondents are the same from time to time, while others are not. I can see that from the respondent ID. My questions is how to analyze this in SAS? I would normally use a Proc Mixed with the repeated or random option to specificy the respondent ID, but what should I do in this case? I could simply analyze the data as unpaired samples, but then I would loose statistical power. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to deal with unbalanced repeated measures design in your data. Mixed models, as implemented in PROC MIXED, are able to handle unbalanced longitudinal data via maximum likelihood and use all observations with at least one response value. The problem could be, however, that the missingness pattern introduces bias in your analyses. Therefore, as a first step I would recommend exploring how random the respondents appear in multiple surveys, i.e. try to get sense of what kind of missingness pattern you are dealing with. Maximum likelihood estimation assumes that the data is missing completely at random (MCAR) or missing at random (MAR). To test for MCAR, you can use Little's test (SAS macro available here http://www.appliedmissingdata.com/macro-programs.html). If the data is not MCAR, you can proceed by comparing mean responses between groups of respondents who have just one survey completed vs. 2-3 surveys vs. 4-6 surveys. If you have demographic data available, check if missingness can be explained by any of the demographic characteristics. This paper (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi24/Stats/p262-24.pdf) provides more details on how missing data can affect repeated measures models. Finally, if you strongly suspect that your data is missing not at random (MNAR), then a sensitivity analysis should be performed to see how different scenarios affect your estimates. PROC MI in SAS has an MNAR option to conduct sensitivity analysis.